# Laravel route getting ruined when trying to reach HTTP request

Tags: laravel, api, xampp, laravel-passport

Currently I have successfully setup my `Laravel Passport API`

Using `Laravel 5.8`.

I have this `httpd-vhosts.conf` config for my api

PORT: 80

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName <sub-domain>.<domain>.com
ServerAlias <sub-domain>.<domain>.com
Redirect permanent / https://<sub-domain>.<domain>.com
</VirtualHost>
```

PORT: 443

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
   DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/api_tk/public"
   <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/api_tk/public">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
   </Directory>
   ServerName <sub-domain>.<domain>.com
   ServerAlias <sub-domain>.<domain>.com

   ErrorLog "logs/API-error_log"
   CustomLog "logs/API-access_log" common

   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPassMatch /fingerprint http://localhost:5000
   ProxyPassReverse /fingerprint http://localhost:5000
   RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
   RequestHeader set X-FOrwarded-Port 443

   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile "/opt/lampp/htdocs/ssl_key/svs-file.crt"
   SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/lampp/htdocs/ssl_key/private_new.key"
   SSLCACertificateFile "/opt/lampp/htdocs/ssl_key/svs-bundle-file.crt"
</VirtualHost>
```

443 is working fine I can see my HTTPS SSL Lock sign on my browser

But

When I try to do HTTP request

Laravel API always getting ruined.

I have route like this

https://..com/api/login

and this is working fine

But when I tried to do HTTP request like this

`http://<sub-domain>.<domain>.com/api/login`

it always end up to

`https://<sub-domain>.<domain>.comapi/login`

Where the slash is missing. This is because of the `redirect permanent` on my PORT 80 config.

[image]

I have this route for my api. (api.php)

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
return $request->user();
});


Route::post('/timekeeping','Auth\Api\AuthController@timekeeping');

Route::post('/login','Auth\Api\AuthController@login');

Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {

Route::post('/timekeeping_app','Auth\Api\AuthController@timekeeping_app');

Route::post('/logout','Auth\Api\AuthController@logout');

Route::post('/register','Auth\Api\AuthController@register');

Route::post('/show_dtr_list','Auth\Api\AuthController@show_dtr_list');

Route::post('/update','Auth\Api\AuthController@update');

Route::post('/delete','Auth\Api\AuthController@delete');

Route::post('/search_user','Auth\Api\AuthController@search_user');

Route::get('/current_time','Auth\Api\AuthController@current_time');

});
```

How can I prevent this?

**UPDATE**

Tried to do edit my vhosts config like this

`Redirect permanent "/" "https://<sub-domain>.<domain>.com/"`

And

`Redirect permanent / https://<sub-domain>.<domain>.com\/`

But this gives me an output like this

[image]

Comment: Two options: 1. try adding the trailing slash and quoting the urls `Redirect permanent "/" "https://<sub-domain>.<domain>.com/"`; or 2. try escaping the trailing slash with a backslash: `Redirect permanent / https://<sub-domain>.<domain>.com\/`

Comment: this works and it redirects to https and reached my api project but the problem is if I try to do that 2 options this gives me an output like this `https://<sub-domain>.<domain>.com//api/login` there is extra slash included, but it should be `https://<sub-domain>.<domain>.com/api/login`

Answer (score 0):

try do add slash under your apache virtual host settings:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName <sub-domain>.<domain>.com
ServerAlias <sub-domain>.<domain>.com
# fix below
Redirect permanent / https://<sub-domain>.<domain>.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: hmm... cannot guarantee 100%, but this should not be Laravel issue, this is apache, so play with that, change settings, try other redirects, for example with `/api` at the end, make sure you restart apache, whatever...